# Otroslogviewer: how to display date information beside the time part?

Tags: otroslogviewer

Otroslogviewer is a stunning log viewer.
The log display shows the time column without the date part of the log.

Is it possible to show the date part of the log entry?

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OtrosLogViewer displays data-time in log details component below. Currently We are not supporting Date-time formatting in log events table.
If you think it's useful please open feature request at [OtrosLogViewer bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/issues/)

Answer (score 1):

Get olv source:

```
git clone https://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/
```

Then edit the date format in:

```
otroslogviewer/OtrosLogViewer-app/src/main/java/pl/otros/logview/gui/renderers/DateRenderer.java
```

to, say, `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss .SSS"` and compile with:

```
$ ./gradlew clean test jar dist
```

You will find the compiled olv in:

```
otroslogviewer/OtrosAppDist/build/distributions/olv-....zip
```

Answer (score 0):

LogMX is another log viewer, and it displays both date & time: [www.logmx.com](http://www.logmx.com).
It can read any log format from any source, and can do a lot.